# Allocating 2D array dynamically

Tags: c

My task is to make a 2D array 2xn from values given in A and B which have n elements.

I found this way to allocate memory for 2D array and it works but I don't understand if or why it is correct

```
int **tab2D(int A[],int B[],int n)
{
    int **newTab = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    newTab[0] = A;
    newTab[1] = B;
    return newTab;
}
```

I know there are other ways to do this but I'm curious about this one.

Comment: because malloc returns contiguous memory.

Comment: Duplicate: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your code it should work like this.

```
int **tab2D(int A[],int B[],int n)
```

can be seen as

```
int **tab2D(int *A,int *B, int n)
```

so you pass pointers to the two arrays which are already allocated.
You then allocate some memory for the pointers-to-pointers

```
 int **newTab = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

which I think should be

```
 int **newTab = malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
```

instead, because you have `A` and `B`, which are both the same length `n`, I assume. Then you dereference the new pointer-to-pointers and assign the pointers to your arrays

```
newTab[0] = A;
newTab[1] = B;
```

which could be written as

```
*newTab = A;
*(newTab + 1) = B;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 2D array of `int`s, is an array of pointers to `int`.

It works because each element of the array points to an address containing an array of `int`s

A similar code using the stack, just to show why it works:

```
int a[] = {1, 2};
int b[] = {3, 4};
int *arr[] = {a, b};
```

A real 2D array is supposed to work in contiguous areas (without fragmentation), you can use pointers to VLA's to achieve this:

```
int rows, cols;

scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols);

int (*arr)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int [rows][cols]));
```

Comment: Voted down because putting the code shown in this answer, `int *arr[] = {a, b};`, into the OP’s function would break the program, as the function returns the array, but the `arr` of `int *arr[] = {a, b};` ceases to exist when the function returns.

Comment: Additionally, it is questionable whether the statement that “This [a pointer to a pointer to `int`] is not a 2D array…” is true. Neither a pointer to a pointer nor an array of arrays is a first-order (that is, an entity built into the language) two-dimensional array in C. But both function as a two-dimensional array, and it is as legitimate to describe them as a two-dimensional array as it is to describe `double sec(double x) { return 1/cos(x); }` as a secant function even though C has no built-in secant function. We can make new things out of other things, including two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Even if you can use subset array notation in the OPs code, it is not a 2D array (as the title suggests), arrays must be placed in contiguous areas. The snippet was an example of an analogue code and was not intended to be used as a replacement.

Comment: (a) An object that behaves like a two-dimensional array serves the purposes of a two-dimensional array and is a two-dimensional array. As I wrote, it is not a two-dimensional array built-in to the language as an element. it is constructed. A thing that is constructed nonetheless exists. (b) If the code was intended as an example and not intended to be used as a replacement, that should be stated. Readers, especially novices who are just learning these concepts, cannot be expected to read your mind. As the answer currently stands, “Your code could also be written as…”, it misleads the reader.

Comment: _An object that behaves like a two-dimensional array serves the purposes of a two-dimensional array and is a two-dimensional array._ No, it is important to call things by their name, my example using VLAs is a real 2D array, OPs is not, you can confirm what I say in any definition of what an array is.

Comment: I believe (but Im not  pretty sure) that OPs construction is usually called look-up table.

Comment: You are right about the second point, it can be mislead. Edited.

Comment: I am calling a thing by its name. `int B[4][5]` is a two-dimensional array. It is an array. It has two dimensions. It is laid out in memory as a two-dimensional array. It is **constructed** in C by making an array of arrays. The result of the construction is a two-dimensional array. It is addressed in two dimensions. The fact that it is a constructed two-dimensional array instead of an atomically native two-dimensional array does not change what it **is**, only **how** it was made. A building constructed of bricks is a building, not just bricks. When you make a new thing, you have a new thing.